# Mob Spawner not spawning anything

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing the latest snapshot 1.16 20w16a of Minecraft in **Survival Mode** and **Normal Difficulty**(not peaceful). I have built a simple Mob Farm following an episode of pixlriffs (here is the [link](https://youtu.be/K9qbH5HEE6g)). For some reason, even after maintaining a distance of 24 blocks, fully covering the spawning blocks, building the spawner in ocean, There are almost no mobs spawning. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wZEi.jpg) are some screenshots taken in the game. Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

Comment: Are you sure there's no caves below this area? Mobs could spawn in there.

Comment: On the screenshot it says E: 2/104, pretty sure you are hitting the mob cap. Try afk-ing about 100 blocks above the mob killing point

Comment: Seems like Mob cap was the issue, I rebuilt the spawner at y = 194 and It's working decent, Thanks to both of you

Answer (score 1):

So, as [Kcats](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/24472/kcats) commented, I was hitting the mob cap, so no mobs were spawning. After rebuilding the spawner at y=194, It's working at decent efficiency.